# SQL Pivot transforming rows into columns

Tags: sql, pivot

Ok. Say I have the data represented by the temp table.

```
create table temp
 (
     ID varchar(max),
     DateTransmitted datetime,
     tagname varchar(max),
     Operator varchar(max),
     Tanknumber varchar(max),
     value float
  )

insert into temp values ( '1gk','2012-01-01 00:00:00.000','TI|A','bob','TK1',   1000.00)    
insert into temp values ('1gk', '2012-01-01 00:00:00.000','TI|B','bob','TK1',  500.00)    
insert into temp values ( '1gk','2012-01-01 00:00:00.000','TI|C','bob','TK1',  800.00)    
insert into temp values ( '2gk','2012-01-01 00:00:00.000','TI|D','bob','TK1',  700.00)    
insert into temp values ( '1gk','2012-01-01 00:00:02.000','TI|E','bob','TK1', 1100.00)    
insert into temp values ( '1gk','2012-01-01 00:00:01.000','TI|F','bob','TK1', 1100.00)
```

I can transform the data with the following dynamic sql.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.tagname) 
            FROM temp c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT 
operator, DateTransmitted, tanknumber,' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select ID
                    ,DateTransmitted
                    ,operator
                    ,Tanknumber
                    , value
                    , tagname
                from temp
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(value)
                for tagname in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)

drop table temp
```

The problem is with last 2 entries into the temp table. The dates are different; even though the data is related and should be displayed in the same row because of the ID which in reality is different for each group of data. My question is how can I end up with the result of this query giving two rows. 1 with the data for id '1gk' and another with the data for '2gk' at and average or minimum (which ever is easier) timestamp for the data for each ID.

IE 
1gk would have the following data

values ( '1gk','2012-01-01 00:00:00.000','TI|A','bob','TK1',   1000.00)

values ('1gk', '2012-01-01 00:00:00.000','TI|B','bob','TK1',  500.00)

values ( '1gk','2012-01-01 00:00:00.000','TI|C','bob','TK1',  800.00)

values ( '1gk','2012-01-01 00:00:00.000','TI|E','bob','TK1', 1100.00)

values ( '1gk','2012-01-01 00:00:00.000','TI|F','bob','TK1', 1100.00)

Comment: What makes those two records related? What are exact deterministic rules? Can we just drop time part of `DateTransmited`?

Comment: the two records are related by the unique identifier for the group of records in this case '1gk'. IE no other data would ever have the id '1gk'. The time part of Date Transmitted cannot simply be dropped as stated above I would like to get the min DateTransmitted for the group to be the DateTransmitted.

Comment: What database system you're using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ensure that for each ID all `DateTransmitted` values passed to the pivot function are equal, you could do this using something like:

```
DateTransmitted = MIN(DateTransmitted) OVER(PARTITION BY ID)
```

*If your logic is that you want the first DateTransmitted for each ID, if not you can change the aggregate as required.*

So your query becomes:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.tagname) 
            FROM temp c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'');

set @query = 'SELECT 
operator, DateTransmitted, tanknumber,' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select ID
                    ,DateTransmitted = MIN(DateTransmitted) OVER(PARTITION BY ID)
                    ,operator
                    ,Tanknumber
                    , value
                    , tagname
                from temp
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                    max(value)
                for tagname in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p ';

execute(@query);
```

**[Example on SQL-Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/44b4c/2)**